# Record is too large MS Access runtime error

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an abnormally large table for one of my applications in MS Access. It violently breaks some rules of normalization, but is otherwise fine for this small application. It has ~100 fields(columns). I have read the [limitation specifications here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx)
but can't see where I violate any of these. Most of the fields are text fields, and range from a couple words to a couple of sentences. My questions are:

1. Is there a way to get a more descriptive error than "record is too large", so that I can determine how to make it smaller?
2. Would changing my 'text' fields to 'memo' fields decrease the size of my record?

At first glance, of all of the specifications potentially violated, this **:Number of characters in a record (excluding Memo and OLE Object fields) when the UnicodeCompression property of the fields is set to Yes :: 4,000**
appears to be the most likely culprit.

3. Would this violation potentially give the "record is too large" runtime error(while filling out a form).
4. Would setting the UnicodeCompression property to 'no' positively or negatively impact the performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memo fields are likely to be the answer. The record limitation rules do not include memo data type.

Comment: I just copied my data over and switched the fields to 'memo' instead of 'text.' I am getting a 'too many fields defined' error when trying to save the table design. I am under the limit of 256. Do you know if there is a maximum number of memo fields allowed for a table?

Comment: problem/solution for my previous comment:  The internal column count that Microsoft Access uses to track the number of fields in the table has reached 255, even though you may have fewer than 255 fields in the table. This can happen because Microsoft Access does not change the internal column count when you delete a field. Microsoft Access also creates a new field (increasing the internal column count by 1) for every field whose properties you modify. Solution for me was to just copy the table over to a new one, then rename it to match the original.

Comment: @Scott "does not change the internal column count when you delete a field" - Have you tried a db compact and repair as that may sort that problem out?

Comment: @Matt I worked around it by just copying the table ove to a new one and renaming it. I haven't been able to use my 'Compact and Repair' tool due to a "selected collating sequence not supported with the specified file format" error.

Comment: Are you using General - Legacy in Access 2007/10 for your sort order? If not, try it (Options).

Comment: I had read up on it when I was working on the problem and most said to use 'General.' Having said that, I took your advice and changed it to "General - Legacy" and I can now run 'compact and repair' without getting a 'selected collating sequence not supported with the specified file format' error. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Seems the limit for fields is 2000 bytes (Memo and OLE are not counted with this restriction). With ~100 fields, you are likely to be hitting that limit.

Solutions are to normalize the table, or convert some fields to Memo fields.

Comment: I think I will just copy the table over and convert a lot of my fields to 'memo.' This will save me the trouble of having to re-write queries and code for the forms (if I normalized it, I would have to do this.) Since this is a small one-off project, and highly unlikely to grow, I'm just gonna bite the bullet and leave it un-normalized.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is too late, but i solved this problem compacting/reparing the database file