# microsoft access database - "record too large" exception

Tags: c++, database, mfc

I have some code which reads from an MS Access database. That code is as follows:

```
CDatabase database;
CString sDriver = "MICROSOFT ACCESS DRIVER (*.mdb)";
CString sDsn;
CString sFile = "MyDB.mdb";
CString sField;

// Build ODBC connection string
sDsn.Format("ODBC;DRIVER={%s};DSN='';DBQ=%s", sDriver, sFile);
TRY
{
    // Open the database
    database.Open(NULL, false, false, sDsn);

    // Allocate the recordset
    CRecordset recset(&database);

    // Execute the query
    recset.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, "SELECT NAME FROM INFOTABLE", CRecordset::readOnly);

    // Loop through each record
    while( !recset.IsEOF() )
    {
        // Copy each column into a variable
        recset.GetFieldValue("NAME", sField);

        // Add the obtained field to a drop-down box
        m_dropDown.AddString(sField);

        // goto next record
        recset.MoveNext();
    }
    // Close the database
    database.Close();
}
CATCH(CDBException, e)
{
    // If a database exception occured, show error msg
    AfxMessageBox("Database error: "+e->m_strError);
}
END_CATCH;
```

My problem is, an exception is thrown **sometimes**. The message box displays,

```
Database error: Record too large
```

My database has > 30000 records.

Why does this exception occur? Also, why does it occur *sometimes*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could search for an answer by yourself, but anyway quoting [MSDN support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/111304) -

> Records in a table... in a Microsoft Access database
>   are limited to slightly under 2K, not counting Memo fields. The
>   "Record is too large" error occurs when you enter data into such a
>   record, not when you define the table structure.

And you can try to use memo types as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190256/record-is-too-large-ms-access-runtime-error) suggests.

Comment: I tried searching for quite a while. I never saw that article o_O Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Also, using the memo types is not an option for me because I didn't (and can't) create the database. Thanks anyway! Oh also, why does that exception occur only sometimes?