# Ms Access Record Too large - French Characters

Tags: ms-access

I hi there guys I've tried a few things. Looked at this answer:[Record is too large MS Access runtime error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190256/record-is-too-large-ms-access-runtime-error).

Tried memo fields, compact and repairs the database file and nothing has worked. As far as i can see everything in the table is okay according to this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-specifications-0cf3c66f-9cf2-4e32-9568-98c1025bb47c?ocmsassetID=HA010341462&CorrelationId=49a62e69-cf72-400b-aad8-302c3b9d6ff0&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US.

So the table has 87 columns(alpha-numerical), some columns have no characters other have 200, which i cant breakdown sadly. There are some records which have more than 2000 characters however, the one in question only has 1908 unless which i suspect might be the case that it has something to do with the french characters(accents etc.). Thank you very much for any help. I'll try and reply as quickly as possible.

The section where the code breaks is:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select " & TableName & ".* FROM " & TableName & ";")
        If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
            rs.MoveFirst
                Do Until rs.EOF = True
                    DirName = rs!DEARNAME
                    RegNumbers = rs!REG
                    Call SurnameFinder2(DirName, RegNumbers)
                    rs.Edit
                    rs!RegSur = DirID
                    rs.Update
                    rs.MoveNext
                Loop
        Else
            MsgBox ("Import Failed")
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

It calls this function:

```
Public Function SurnameFinder2(DirectorName, RegNo) As String
    Dim SQLInsertQuery
    Dim DirectorName2 As String
    Dim Regno3 As String
    Dim Lngstr As Long
    Dim lSpace As Long
    Dim StrName As String
    Dim Space As Long

    StrName = Trim(DirectorName)
    Lngstr = Len(StrName)
    Testing = InStrRev(StrName, " ", , vbTextCompare)
    Space = Lngstr - Testing
    Surname = Trim(Right(StrName, Space))
    DirID = RegNo & Surname

End Function
```

Comment: Please start by describing what's going on. This question currently is a bit chaotic, you start with a link, then continue with what you've tried and another link, and then a bit of a description, but it's not clear to me at all what you need help with.

Comment: Hi there Erik. Pretty much the user uploads a file that he has been working with. We need to remove the people who have asked to be unsubscribed from our newspaper. This happens at the ends of the process. Which is when the table gets to about 87 columns. This excel spreadsheet gets uploaded to the database. It gets one extra column which creates the PK and i remove where the PK matches in our remove table.

Comment: The PK in question is: 682038385TRANDUC. But we have some like: 612040147FICHTENBERG which are longer but work fine

Comment: Please include that in your question, and try to make the whole thing a bit more logical. Add relevant things like table schema, code importing, etc. Try to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Table schema is a bit more tricky as that can change from user to user. But its always alphanumerical. The Problem Field is RegSur(ShortText, 255) it created with the following: REG, DEARNAME who are also both (ShortText,255)

Comment: I have my doubts that the accented characters are the source of the problem. The 2000-character limit is a pessimistic approximation of the hard limit of a row having to fit in a 4KB data page, but characters in the Windows-1252 character set (which includes French accented characters) are normally stored as one byte, not two. (Other characters like Greek, Russian, etc. consume 2 bytes.) Still, the limit is 2000 characters regardless. Anyway, when you say that you "Tried memo fields" did you convert *all* of the TEXT(255) fields to MEMO fields?

Comment: No not all only the 10 columns which have the largest number of characters in them. I think in Ms Access 2016 their called long text now if i am not mistaken. On average those 10 have about 1000 character between them so i thought i would just start with them